# In Rust, what is the difference between clone() and to_owned()?

Tags: rust

In Rust, `Clone` is a trait that specifies the `clone` method (and `clone_from`).  Some traits, like `StrSlice` and `CloneableVector`  specify a `to_owned` fn.  Why would an implementation need both?  What is the difference?

I did an experiment with Rust strings, which have both methods, and it demonstrates that there is a difference, but I don't understand it:

```rust
fn main() {
    test_clone();
    test_to_owned();
}

// compiles and runs fine    
fn test_clone() {
    let s1: &'static str = "I am static";
    let s2 = "I am boxed and owned".to_string();

    let c1 = s1.clone();
    let c2 = s2.clone();

    println!("{:?}", c1);
    println!("{:?}", c2);

    println!("{:?}", c1 == s1);  // prints true
    println!("{:?}", c2 == s2);  // prints true
}

fn test_to_owned() {
    let s1: &'static str = "I am static";
    let s2 = "I am boxed and owned".to_string();

    let c1 = s1.to_owned();
    let c2 = s2.to_owned();

    println!("{:?}", c1);
    println!("{:?}", c2);

    println!("{:?}", c1 == s1);   // compile-time error here (see below)
    println!("{:?}", c2 == s2);
}
```

The compile time error for the `to_owned` example is:

```
error: mismatched types: expected `~str` but found `&'static str` 
(str storage differs: expected `~` but found `&'static `)
clone.rs:30     println!("{:?}", c1 == s1);
```

Why would the first example work but not the second?

Comment: This error is not reproducible anymore in the current Rust (see in the [Playground](http://is.gd/2bYnMW) where I replaced `~"abc"` with `"abc".to_string()`

Comment: I updated the example to use `to_string()` rather than the older '~' notation.  However, it is interesting that this new version (your playground entry) now compiles and runs fine. Did a change in the `==` operator/fn happen so that it can compare `&str` and `String` types for value equality?

Comment: this all works just fine now see
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4c0c2e3ee46091956834da5c4d23f661

Answer (score 114, accepted):

`.clone()` returns its receiver. `clone()` on a `&str` returns a `&str`. If you want a `String`, you need a different method, which in this case is `.to_owned()`.

For most types, `clone()` is sufficient because it's only defined on the underlying type and not on the reference type. But for `str` and `[T]`, `clone()` is implemented on the reference type (`&str` and `&[T]`), and therefore it has the wrong type. It's also implemented on the owned types (`String` and `Vec<T>`), and in that case `clone()` will return another owned value.

Your first example works because `c1` and `s1` (and `c2` and `s2`) have the same types. Your second example fails because they don't (`c1` is `String` whereas `s1` is `&str`). That's a perfect example of why the separate methods are necessary.

---

As of current Rust, both now compile, but in `test_clone()` `c1` is a `&str` and in `test_to_owned()` it's a `String`. I'm pretty sure it compiles as Rust is now more lenient about automatically referencing and dereferencing values. In this particular example I believe the `c1 == s1` line is compiled as though it said `&*c1 == s1`. If you wish to prove the types involved you can add a deliberate type error, such as `let _: i32 = c1;` and the error message will show the type.

Comment: The code now compiles on the latest version of Rust. What changed?

Comment: @OmarAbid I believe Rust is now more lenient about automatically taking references to values. The line `c1 == s1` I think ends up compiled as `&*c1 == s1`, which is a `&str == &str` comparison. Note that `c1` in the `test_to_owned()` example is still a `String`.

Comment: ```#[test]
fn name() {
    let s1 = String::from("hello ");
    assert_eq!(s1, s1.clone());
    assert_eq!(s1, s1.to_owned());
}
``` this seems to be all the same

Comment: "For most types, `clone()` is sufficient because it's only defined on the underlying type and not on the reference type" — this is a bit backwards. [`Clone` is implemented on all `&T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#impl-Clone-for-%26T) because immutable references are `Copy`. The difference is that ordinarily, deref coercion will attempt to turn `(&T)::clone()` into `T::clone()` and clone the pointed-to object. But when `T: !Sized`, like with `str`, there is no `Clone` implementation on `T`, so deref coercion fails and the only choice is to clone the `&T`.