# When does to_owned() not clone?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

The [docs for to_owned()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html#tymethod.to_owned) state:

> Creates owned data from borrowed data, usually by cloning.

But it is unstated the conditions under which cloning does not occur.  "Usually" is quite vague, and I am trying to remove `.clone()` calls for performance reasons.

Can someone clarify?

Comment: > Some types make it possible to go from borrowed to owned, usually by implementing the Clone trait. But Clone works only for going from &T to T. The ToOwned trait generalizes Clone to construct owned data from any borrow of a given type.

Comment: 99% of case to_owned will allocate memory.

Comment: The types in the standard library which implement `ToOwned` but not `Clone` are all unsized types with an allocated owned version, like `str` (`Owned = String`), `Path` (`PathBuf`), `[T]` (`Vec<T>`), etc. That's pretty much all there is to it.

Comment: And the entire point of `ToOwned` is to create an owned copy of a borrowed one, unless it's applied to a `Copy` type, `Clone` seems like the least it would do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Rust, what is the difference between clone() and to\_owned()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264502/in-rust-what-is-the-difference-between-clone-and-to-owned)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `to_owned` method is part of the [`ToOwned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html) trait, because of this it cannot guarantee that the struct implementing the trait will clone or not clone the instance `to_owned` is being called upon. The blanket implementation for the `ToOwned` trait does call `clone`, and it is rarely manually implemented, which is one of the reasons almost every call to `to_owned` will result in a cloning.

Additionally, as pointed out by @Sven Marnach, any struct which derives `Clone` receives the blanket implementation and cannot implement its own implementation of `ToOwned`, making calls to the blanket imp even more common.

See below for the [blanket implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/borrow.rs.html#80-92) of `ToOwned`

```rust
impl<T> ToOwned for T
where
    T: Clone,
{
    type Owned = T;
    fn to_owned(&self) -> T {
        self.clone()
    }

    fn clone_into(&self, target: &mut T) {
        target.clone_from(self);
    }
}
```

Comment: "like the `Copy` trait, it is rarely manually implemented" – `Copy` is a marker trait without any methods. It's usually "implemented" by `#[derive(Copy)]`. An explicit implementation of `Copy` would look like `impl Coppy for Foo {}`, so there is nothing to gain over simply deriving it. This is different from `ToOwned`: If your type is `Clone`, you get the blanket implementation of `ToOwned` and _can't_ implement the trait yourself. If you type isn't `Clone` and you need `ToOwned`, you _have to_ implement it yourself.

Comment: Thats a good distinction to make. I'll update the answer to be more accurate