# What is the difference between to_owned() and clone() in this context?

Tags: rust

```
pub fn set(&mut self, key: String, value: String) -> Result<()> {
    let cmd = Command::Set {
        key: key.clone(),
        value: value.to_owned(),
    };
    serde_json::to_writer(&mut self.writer, &cmd)?;
    self.writer.flush()?;
    self.map.insert(key, value);
    Ok(())
}
```

In this function I can either use `.clone()` or `to_owned()` to create that struct from my 2 function parameter `String`'s `key` and `value`. What is the difference and which would be better for this situation?

Comment: Related: [In Rust, what is the difference between clone() and to_owned()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22264502)

Answer (score 3):

The difference is explained in the docs of the [ToOwned](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html) trait:

> Some types make it possible to go from borrowed to owned, usually by
> implementing the `Clone` trait.
>
> But `Clone` works only for going from `&T` to `T`. The `ToOwned` trait
> generalizes Clone to construct owned data from any borrow of a given
> type.

In your particular case, however, given that you build a `cmd` for the whole purpose of passing a reference to it to `serde_json::to_writer(&mut self.writer, &cmd)?;`, you might want to modify the struct's fields to be just references to the types, something like this:

```rust
struct Cmd<'s> {
    key: &'s str,
    value: &'s str,
}
```

This will avoid you having to clone anything.